# anchor: how to init a PDA and close it in the same method?

Tags: anchor

I would like to create a PDA and close it in the same method, but can't find how.

if i use `init` and `close`, it says i should add `mut`, but if i add `mut`, it says it can't be used with `init`.

Why do i need to create and close the account in the same method ?
this account is used in a CPI to receive funds and then send them back to other accounts.

The only solution i can see is creating this account in another method before calling this one, but if i can avoid it, that would be wonderfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try directly modifying the lamport balance of the PDA within the instruction where you `init` the account.

For example,

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
declare_id!("CShtV32yVjfxG2kyGkpTcx4jbxYm6ZJBqfakkydgdyAY");

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.new_account.data = data;
        msg!("Changed data to: {}!", data);

        let amount = **ctx
            .accounts
            .new_account
            .to_account_info()
            .try_borrow_mut_lamports()?;

        msg!("Lamports: {}!", amount);

        **ctx
            .accounts
            .new_account
            .to_account_info()
            .try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount;

        **ctx.accounts.signer.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64,
}
```

Comment: removing all the lamports is the same as close an account ? (for a pda i mean)

Comment: yep, when you transfer out all the lamports from an account it effectively closes the account

Comment: In addition to removing all the lamports, to completely close an account, you should set its owner to the system program and reallocate its size to 0

Comment: Anybody looking for more info on how this is done.. https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/how-to-change-owner-of-owned-account